# Output file from Archive

Tags: tar

Given that I have this archive `my_archive.tar.gz` which has this file in it: `README`. How can I output the content of `README` without having to extract the archive?

OS: Debian 7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **z** to (g)unzip, **x** to extract, with **f** from archive file. Then add also option **-O** to direct extracted files to standard output.

```
tar xzf my_archive.tar.gz folder/README.txt -O
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802695/hp-ux-how-can-i-read-a-text-file-from-tar-archive-without-extracting-it)